# Are guide animals Ochel nefesh on Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot, handicap-disabled-impair, ochel-nefesh

According to Halacha, certain forms of Melacha are permissible on Yom Tov for needs of the holiday, notably cooking and carrying.

My question is, if someone lives outside a kosher Eruv and they’re disabled/blind, can they move a guide animal outside as Ochel nefesh to go to synagogue on Yom Tov?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gemara on [Beitza 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Beitzah.12a.2?lang=bi) learns from Beit Hillel that whenever a *melacha* is permitted for the sake of *ochel nefesh*, it is also permitted more generally. See [OC 518:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.518.1?lang=bi) where the Rema adds there needs to be at least some holiday-related need

> Since carrying was permitted for the sake of food preparation, it was
> also permitted for the sake of non-(food preparation), such as (for
> the sake of) a minor, a Lulav, a Sefer Torah, and vessels.  Rema:
> (Provided) that one needs them a bit [...]

As such case your case feels perfectly permitted.

Comment: I am going with your assumption that using a guide dog is an issue of carrying, in reality it is more likely to be an issue of muktzeh or actually permitted if the person is blind. But you really asked how broad the issue of carrying is on Yom Tov and that is what I am answering.